# Using same entity twice in another entity in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, one-to-one

Let us say a class/entity named student which contains an id, father's occupation and mother's occupation and the entity classes are like this

Student class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true, updatable = false)
    private int id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "occupationId")
    Occupation fathersOccupation;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "occupationId")
    Occupation mothersOccupation;

}
```

and the Occupation class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "occupation")
public class Occupation {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "occupationId")
    int occupationId;

    @Column
    String title;

}
```

When I tried `@OneToOne` mapping for both father's occupation and mother's occupation it is throwing exception,`Repeated column in mapping for entity`. I tried adding `@Column(name="<columnName>")`, but it is not allowed. I really want those two fields,`fathersOccupation` and `mothersOccupation` with `oneToOne` mapping in the student table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@JoinColumn specify the name of the FK Column in your entity.

Your student entity have 2 FKs toward occupation, one for fathersOccupation and another one for mothersOccupation and you define mapping twice for the same. Ideally you should have **fathers_occupation_id** and **mothers_occupation_id** field in your student table and same attributes in your entity.

So you should put for each one the corresponding column name in your student table.

```
@JoinColumn(name ="fathers_occupation_id")
Occupation fathersOccupation;

@JoinColumn(name="mothers_occupation_id")
Occupation mothersOccupation;
```

Answer (score 3):

If someone interesting in, the solution that worked for me was to rename mapping field in entity with @ManyToOne annotation and add prefix before "account_id":

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "from_account_id") // add from_
private Account fromAcc;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "to_account_id") // add to_
private Account toAcc;
```

Comment: and what to mention in Account Entity for ManyToOne annotaion.